# Microsoft Access CODED UI Tests Control id recording

Tags: coded-ui-tests, test-project

I have implemented a test framework trough coded UI to test msaccess application which has some buttons and dialog boxes popping up.

i have a strange problem which is, when i use coded UI it actually captures the coordinates for the control. this executes all the tests when i run from the same machine but fails to run the tests wherever the resolution changes or screen re sizes.

please let me know the way by which i can call the controls from a vba application based on their control names or id rather then coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the coordinates is the reason that your tests are failing. These coordinates are referred to the controls themselves just to simulate the exact point you clicked on the control.

See this link: [Why are we using coordinate based actions in Coded UI Test?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2012/03/16/faq-why-are-we-using-coordinate-based-actions-in-coded-ui-test.aspx)